# configure keeps finding tcmalloc. How?

Tags: autoconf, libtool, tcmalloc, cray

I'm building NWChem on Cray. libtcmalloc_minimal is already added to an archive file by the cc in my Cray environment. In my configure routine, it explicitly appends a second -ltcmalloc_minimal resulting in a multiple definition and a configure fail. But none of the configure.* files or makefiles (or *any* files included with NWChem) contain any reference to tcmalloc_minimal.

- How is tcmalloc_minimal getting in there?
- How can I keep it out?

Comment: You’re better off filing these issues with the NWChem user forum or on GitHub. It’s pure luck that I, a part-time NWChem developer and Cray user, saw this.

Answer (score 0):

The autoconf _AC_FC_LIBRARY_LDFLAGS macro (called as part of AC_PROG_FC) and other macros querying library flags and objects retrieves this value from the verbose compiler output (which contains this library on Cray systems). For this reason Cray's patched autoconf contains a change of the above macro to get rid of the flag. I'm currently in the process of figuring out an override to the macro so configure scripts produced by unpatched versions of autoconf also work on Cray systems. I'll post an update once I've figured out something reliably working.